# (0 , _moment2.default)(...).format(...).isValid is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs

this is a valid birthday:

1372/24/02

my code:

```
  var isValidBirthDay = moment('1372/24/02', 'fa', true).format("YYYY/MM/DD").isValid()
```

but I got this error message:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:63 (0 , _moment2.default)(...).format(...).isValid is not a function


"moment": "^2.22.2",
```

my programming language is `react-native`

Comment: Your programming language is JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.format()` returns a JavaScript `String`, and you can't call `.isValid()` on a string.

First validate, then format:

```
var birthday = moment('1372/24/02', 'fa', true);
var isValidBirthday = birthday.isValid();
var formattedBirthday = birthday.format("YYYY/MM/DD");
console.log(formattedBirthday, (isValidBirthday ? "is valid" : "is not valid"));
```

Comment: now I  got this message: `Invalid date is not valid` but my birthday is correct.